# Can't get Symfony demo to work for routing

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to get the getting started guide of Symfony to work and failed at the very first step in creating a router.
Here is the tutorial I am following: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/page_creation.html
And here is the code of my routing.yml :

```
    app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

  luckynumber:
    path:      /lucky/number
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:number}
```

And here is the aimed for controller:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{

    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);
        return new Response("hello", 200);
        }
    }
```

Which can be found at src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php .
However, if I am trying to fire up http://127.0.0.1:8000/lucky/number I get a 404 and the message that Symfony could not find a route.

I tried several different tutorials with no avail, I guess I'm blind to something important. Here is [link to my repo](https://github.com/mattlang88/first_symfony_project), if you need more details.
I appreciate every suggestion!
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use annotated or yaml config routes?

Comment: Going for yaml ...

Comment: Make sure you are in development mode.  Do the ever popular cache clearing.  run bin/console debug:router and see if your route is there.

Comment: Just cleared the cache and looked for the route, but it seems no to be there. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Oh and how to I make sure that I am in dev mode?

Comment: what happens if you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/lucky/number

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, I created two demo projects and was furiously making changes to the second, while having a local server run for the first, wondering why nothing changes. Actually the comment of @Cerad made me wonder why, if I add die() to app_dev.php and app.php doesn't have any impact.
Thanks folks, I'm out!